# How to return array() in fluent-schema?

Tags: javascript, fastify

I have an object that looks like this:

```
interface LotteryData {
  PROP1: string;
  PROP2: string;
  PROP3: string;
  PROP4: string;
  PROP5: string;
}

interface LotterySuccess {
  name: string;
  data: Array<LotteryData>;
}
```

My schema is like this:

```
const successResponseSchema = S.object()
  .title('About 200 response')
  .description('Some description')
  .prop('name', S.string())
  .definition('data', S.array());
```

When using postman I get back the name but not the data.

I have also tried:

```
const successResponseSchema = S.object()
  .title('About 200 response')
  .description('Some description')
  .prop('name', S.string())
  .prop('data', S.anyOf([S.object()]));
```

Here data is null and I understand that since the data I am sending back in an array and not an object.

The handler that handles the request looks like this:

```
const handler = async (req, reply) => {
  const responseData = await fileManager();

  const response: LotterySuccess = {
    name: responseData.Name,
    data: responseData.Data,
  };

  reply.send(response);
};

export default (server: FastifyInstance) =>

  server.get<null>('/', opts, handler);
```

responseData.Data has the correct values but I am failing to align my success schema to responde with
an array of objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of those seek for hours and once you finaly ask the question you also find an answer.

Want to keep this question since this isn't something easy to find. 
I figured this out by trial and error.

found [this](https://www.fastify.io/docs/master/Fluent-Schema/) to be somewhat helpful.

My final solution:

```
const successResponseSchema = S.object()
  .title('About 200 response')
  .description('Some description')
  .prop('name', S.string())
  .prop(
    'data',
    S.array().items(
      S.object()
        .prop('PROP1', S.string())
        .prop('PROP2', S.string())
    )
  );
```

To be honest I dont feel that this is an answer that covers everything. I can¨t explain why it has to be like this. If anyone can explain that part then great. I will hopefully be able to update this answer with more details in the future.

EDIT: 
@Manuel Spigolon  gave some pointers in the comments.

Changed above to :

```
const successResponseSchema = S.object()
  .title('About 200 response')
  .description('Some description')
  .prop('name', S.string())
  .prop('data', S.array().items(S.object().additionalProperties(true)));
```

This way I did not have to add each prop.

Comment: Your solution is right, it could be helpfull add `.prop('data', S.array().items(S.object().additionalProperties(false)))` to have an array of dynamic object (without defining a schema)

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify#additional-properties) but it could be difficult to find out

Comment: * I ment `additionalProperties(true)`